# Can I change the behavior of up/down arrows in Html Number input without changing the validation behavior?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am working on an MVC application that is used to record billing rates for job cost codes and I am using Html helpers to build a list of inputs on a page like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LineItemRates[i].REG, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
   @class = "reg form-control input-sm", @type = "number", step = "0.01", 
   placeholder = "Regular Time..", @required = "required" } })
```

These inputs work great, but I am wondering if there is an option that I can use so that when a user clicks on the up/down arrows the value will increment by 1 dollar rather than 1 cent, but still validate according to the step="0.01"?

[image: money input arrows]

Currently, it goes up by one cent at a time, which I understand why considering the step="0.01" value. I like using that step value because it makes client-side validation easy being able to rely on Html5 validation.

Is there an easy way for me to change the behavior of the step buttons while retaining the easy validation that this number input provides?

Comment: I finally found an answer on SO that gave a good explanation of this question. The duplicate mentioned above explains why it is not currently possible with html5 to change the step behavior without changing the validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you explicitly specified the step value as "0.01".

If you remove that, it will increase the value , not the decimal fractions.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LineItemRates[i].REG, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
    @class = "reg form-control input-sm", @type = "number", 
    placeholder = "Regular Time..", @required = "required" } })
```

But with this approach, you will loose the decimal fraction part of the number (Assuming your property is decimal/double type) from the input when user clicks on the up /down arrow.

If you want the decimal part, there is no direct way to increase the values before `.` by default. If absolutely needed, you can come up with some crazy-ugly javascript solutions where you keep the original value in a hidden variable or so and on the `change` event, update the value using the original value (Whic h has the decimal fraction part) and keep updating this temp variable value with the new value. But like i mentioned it is ugly and i would stay away from it as much as possible.

Also remember client side validation is just a handy helper. You must always validate input on server.